# Can I use a main class object as a parameter to find the subclass object?

Tags: c#, class, casting, type-conversion

I'm still kinda new at coding so I was wondering if/how this works?

```
//a class with armor with subclasses to say what part of the body it go's
public class Armor
{
    //stuff that applies to all armor          
}
public class HeadArmor : Armor
{
    //stuff for HeadPieces only
}
public class ChestArmor : Armor
{
}
 //etc

//the class that stores what  armor is equiped
public class MainCharacterEquipment
{
    //the class of my maincharacter
    public MainCharacter HeroEquipment { get; set; }

    public HeadArmor HeadSlot { get; set; }
    public ChestArmor ChestSlot { get; set; }
    //etc
    //a constructor that sets all to null

    public void EquipArmor(Armor armor)
    {
        if (armor is HeadArmor)
        {
            HeadSlot = armor; //compile error
        }
        if (armor is ChestArmor)
        {
            ChestSlot = armor; //compile error -> Missing a cast?
        }
        //etc
    }
}
```

If I do this it will ask if I'm missing a cast.
From reading on this forum it seems that a subclass is a type of the mainclass
but not the other way around.

To solve this I could make a method for each subclass of armor. 
Instead of using (Armor armor) as a parameter, I would use the (HeadArmor headArmor), (ChestArmor chestArmor), etc... 
But that seems tedious.
I also read that there is a difference between typeof() and is but I dont realy understand that either.
Preferably I would just cast the object armor to its subclass. Of course, the if function should check whether its not already the subclass (if that makes sense)

ps: There actualy are no instances of Armor objects. Only objects of subclasses are instantiated.  (should it matter)

Comment: try `if ( armor is HeadArmor hArmor ) { HeadSlot = hArmor; } ...` this will also do a cast if the type matches. Of course, there are more solutions to this... but start simple.

Comment: @Korosevar Are you developing that stuff for Unity?  If so pattern matching won't work

Comment: @ Fildor i get error: hArmor does not exist in current context

Comment: You have an error there you u need to do: if (armor is HeadArmor hArmor) { HeadSlot = hArmor;}

Comment: Why not make HeadSlot and ChestSlot both of type Armor? That is when polymorphism shines.

Comment: @Tobias Theel im creating a windows form. its text based

Comment: @CodingYoshi. then you could equip a chestpiece at a headslot. and i try to keep Idtags small.  now i can refer to GetHeadArmorbyId(id) with a foreach loop for every armor piece differently

Comment: You could try what CodingYoshi has suggested + add an Enum EquipSlot which you could throw into a switch-case to estimate the slot

Comment: Which Platform is that? .Net framework 4.7 ? .Net Core? Unity? ... That might exclude some solutions ...

Comment: @Tobias oh wait.. you mean give the class Armor a property that desides att what bodypart the piece can be used

Comment: @thobias .Net framework 4.5

Comment: Then you could use a Visitor Pattern as well while getting rid of "if-else/switch"

Comment: What if the client calls the properties directly instead of `EquipArmor`? You commented: *then you could equip a chestpiece at a headslot*-so what? That would be the the client's fault.

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide more code because right now we have to make too many assumptions. Instead of `//etc` provide some code. Also show the implementation of at least one armor class.

Comment: Give your Armor class an abstract method `EquipWith( MainCharacterEquipment visitor )`. Have the HeadArmor and ChestArmor classes implement it with  `EquipWith( MainCharacterEquipment visitor ){ visitor.XXXArmor = this; }` where XXX = Head or Chest respective. Then all you need to do in `EquipArmor` is `armor.EquipWith( this );` and your MainCharacterEquipment will be automagically equipped at the correct spot. Also, if you later add a "LegArmor" you don't have to touch that method.

Comment: @coding yoshi. yea i gues you are right.

Comment: @fildor i will look into that, it sounds interesting, but Scott answer makes me able to work with it now.

Comment: Fair enough. I invite you to read up on the visitor pattern. It's awesome to break up those "if-else-monsters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the same cast when you do the assignment. The compiler does not carry information through the `if` statement once the initial check has passed.

In your code:

```
if (armor is HeadArmor) // The compiler verifies this is HeadArmor
{
    // The compiler does not carry the information forward.
    // It has no way of knowing, on this line, that armor is still HeadArmor.
    // For all it knows, armor  could be ChestArmor which would be invalid.
    HeadArmor = armor; 
}
```

To fix the error, you need to update your code as follows:

```
if (armor is HeadArmor)
{
    HeadArmor = (HeadArmor)armor; // Lets the compiler know this is HeadArmor.
}
```

Another option could be to use `as` to try and suss out the correct choice.

```
var headArmor = armor as HeadArmor;
if (headArmor != null)
{
    HeadArmor = headArmor;
}
```

Comment: that fixed it. And looks realy clean.  is the (HeadArmor)armor a cast?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (HeadArmor)armor is telling the code to interpret that armor as a HeadArmor even though the type the compiler knows it to be is an Armor.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a Visitor Pattern instead:

```
public abstract class Armor
{
    public abstract void Equip( MainCharacterEquipment mce );
}
public class HeadArmor : Armor
{
    public override void Equip( MainCharacterEquipment mce )
    {
         mce.HeadSlot=this;
    }
}
public class ChestArmor : Armor
{
    public override void Equip( MainCharacterEquipment mce )
    {
         mce.ChestSlot=this;
    }
}
```

Then your MainCharacterEquipment code boils down to:

```
public void EquipArmor(Armor armor)
{
     armor.Equip(this); 
}
```

This gets rid of "if-else" and if you later chose to add more types of armor and Slots, you don't need to touch that code. Just add another XXXXArmor class and it will go to the right slot.

Comment: Is it possible that you have to use public virtual void in abstract class? i get 'cannot declare a body because its maked abstract' in a kinda similiar situation